# Make user interaction inactive while progress bar is visible

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-progressbar

In a dialog fragment , when i use a progress bar (not progress dialog) I want to complete a task and then allow user interaction. It can be achieved with progress dialog by using setCancelable(false) , but how to do it with progress bar ? 
**(Since, getWindow() function doesn't work inside a dialog fragment).**

*Thank you in advance* :)

Comment: In DialogFragment you are inflating the view in `onCreateView()` method, so you can pass the layout there and then interact with the views.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend you doing that since the idea of progress bar is to show the user that something is going on but it should not have anything to do with the fact that they can interact with the screen. (That's one of the reasons why ProgressDialog was deprecated, to encourage not to block the UI when something is loading).

Besides that, answering your question, getWindow can be called from the activity, you can retrieve the activity in your dialog fragment using either requireActivity().getWindow() or getActicity().getWindow() and set the params accordingly to disable user action.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `isLoading` boolean flag, and forbid all interactions while that flag is `true`, and after the work is done, set that flag to `false`